# Function being zero on a set

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, general-topology, volume

> Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a Jordan region ($A$ is nonempty) and let $f : A\to \mathbb{R}, f(a)\geq 0$ for all $a\in A.$ Suppose $f$ is integrable over $A$ and that $\displaystyle\int_A f(x)dx = 0.$ Prove that there exists a $B\subseteq A$ so that $Vol(B) = \int_B 1 dx = 0$ and $f(x) = 0\,\forall x \in A\backslash B.$

I think I should go about this by contradiction. Suppose that for every $B\subseteq A,$ either $Vol(B)\neq 0$ or $\exists x \in A\backslash B$ so that $f(x) >  0.$ Clearly, for any point $a \in A,B= \{a\}\subseteq A$ and $Vol(B) = 0,$ so we need to show that $\forall B\subseteq A, \exists x \in A\backslash B$ is false. Observe that in order for $Vol(B)$ to be $0$, we must have that $Int(B) = 0$ because otherwise we can find a rectangle $R$ inside $B$ so that $Vol(R) < Vol(B) = 0,$ a contradiction. Observe that since $A\cap (B\backslash A) = \emptyset, 0 = \int_A f(x) dx = \int_B f(x)dx + \int_{A\backslash B} f(x)dx\Rightarrow \int_B f(x)dx = -\int_{A\backslash B} f(x)dx.$ Since $f(x) \geq 0$ on $A,$ we have that $\int_{A\backslash B} f(x)dx \geq \int_{A\backslash B} 0 dx = 0\Rightarrow 0\leq \int_B f(x)dx = -\int_{A\backslash B} f(x)dx \leq 0\Rightarrow \int_B f(x) dx = 0.$ Suppose that $Vol(B) = \int_B 1 dx\neq 0.$ Then by definition, $Vol(B) > 0$. Hence $\int_B 1dx > 0.$

> We need to somehow derive a contradiction from this. And we need to show that $\exists B \subseteq A$ so that $\forall x \in A\backslash B, f(x) = 0.$ I think it might be useful to consider when $Int(A) = \emptyset$ and when $Int(A)\neq \emptyset.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $B = \{x \in A : f(x) > 0\}$. We can write $B = \bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^\infty \{x \in A : f(x) > 1/i\}$. Then $Vol(B) = \lim\limits_{i \to \infty} Vol(\{x \in A : f(x) > 1/i\})$. But $Vol(\{x \in A : f(x) > 1/i\}) = 0$, since if the volume were $r > 0$, the integral over $A$ would be at least $r/i > 0$. So $Vol(B) = 0$. And clearly, if $x \in A \setminus B$, $f(x) = 0$.

Comment: are you sure this answer is correct? apparently the proposition is false.

Comment: @Gord452 The answer is natural, simple, and rather clear (maybe there is needed a brief argument why sets $\{x \in A : f(x) > 1/i\}$ are measurable)$. So I expect it is correct.

Comment: @Gord452 What makes you say the proposition is false? Everyone seems to agree this argument is fine. Measurability is obvious; the limit statement uses countable additivity and is fine. I am assuming you're using the Lebesgue measure here, though the Jordan region assumption is then not used.

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson I say the proposition is false because I think it doesn't work for $f(x) = \begin{cases}\frac{1}n,&\text{ if $x = \frac{m}n, \gcd(m,n) = 1$}\\ 0,&\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}.$ Every subset of $[0,1]$ must contain $B = [0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q}\backslash \{0\}$ and yet $Vol(B) = 1$ and $\int_A f(x)dx = 0.$ So clearly, the volume of any subset cannot be zero in this case.

Comment: *every subset $B$ of $[0,1]$ so that $f(x) = 0$ on $A\backslash B$ must contain $\mathbb{Q}\backslash \{0\}.$

Comment: @Gord452 The volume of $[0, 1] \cap \mathbb{Q} - \{0\}$ is 0 in the Lebesque measure, not 1, since it's a countable set. (It's apparently not Jordan-measurable anyway; I have no experience with that "measure".)

Comment: @Gord452 Well there's the problem then. If you don't specify, the default is surely Lebesque, and I was clear that Doctor Who's answer is right for sigma-additive measures. That's surely what everyone else who upvoted was thinking. So, it's not "incorrect" really, it's just that you weren't clear about your setup.

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson I agree.